# I am running Ubuntu 20.04 and cannot seem to get Rhythmbox 3.44 to detect my Gerbera DLNA server even with Grilo addon

Tags: 20.04, rhythmbox

I am running Ubuntu 20.04, and like Rhythmbox (despite it hanging regularly), but would like to access my media from my Gerbera DLNA server.
I added the Grilo plugin, and ensured I had the libraries installed (0.3), but I cannot see any media servers appear in the panels.
I am sure in an earlier version of Ubuntu, this was working well, so I don't know what happened!
(I am hoping this can work, so I can also see it working on a RaspberryPi, so I can play music from my DLNA server on my hi-fi without needing a computer and TV on!)

Please let me know if more details are needed...

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Hello. You may want to start with the plugin support. Here is the URL. https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libs/grilo-plugins-0.3-extra

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and was able to solve with David answer.

First i checked if grilo-plugins was updated with:

```
sudo apt-get -y install grilo-plugins-0.3-base
```

After that i installed :

```
sudo apt-get -y install grilo-plugins-0.3-extra
```